# Masters of Venice - On Delivering Guild Orders

Tags: masters-of-venice

In the game [Masters of Venice](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/40276/masters-venice), what happen if after I have delivered a Guild Order, and upon drawing a new one, I still have enough goods to meet the newly drawn order?

According to the rules, I still take VP and adjust the prices of good as in my first order. However, do I count the second order as a new separate order (hence perhaps giving me more VP than the first order)?

And what does it meant by in the rules that "You do not get to deliver the order" in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [errata posted on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/41929/error/expired/errata-for-the-published-rules) that corrects the rules about delivering Guild Orders, and an [updated set of rules](http://www.rnrgames.com/images/ProductRules/MOVrules.PDF) (from the publisher's site, [also available on BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/41930/mov-rules-with-updates-from-errata-included)) which includes the correction. According to the errata and the new rules with the errata included, you do indeed count the second order as a new order, and thus get more VPs than the first gave you.

> • On page 8 under Guild Hall replace the last
>   paragraph with the one below:
>
> *IMPORTANT! – If you have just delivered a Guild
>   Order, then picked a new Guild Order and happen
>   to have the Resources with you to fill it, you may
>   turn them in immediately. Adjust prices and Orders,
>   and collect VP’s, as described above.*

This is also confirmed by the designer in a [thread on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/550958/question-about-gaining-vp-when-turning-in-guild-or):

> Brian has it correct, the guild orders are placed in front of you to track how many you have completed. The value of the delivery increases for each you deliver. Hence, 3 for the first card delivered, 4 for the second, 5 for the third and 6 thereafter. Let's say you deliver two at the same time, and they happen to be your 2nd and 3rd cards delivered, you would thus receive 9 on that delivery of two cards.

I do not have the original rules before the correction, so I don't know what it said; in particular, in the updated version, I see nothing about "you do not get to deliver the order," so I'm assuming that's something that the updated paragraph has replaced.